# HttpServletRequestのsetAttribute()でセットされた情報を確認したい

Tags: java, servlet

Java ServletのHttpServletRequestオブジェクトに、
setAttribute()でどんな情報がセットされているのか、
json形式などで簡単に確認する方法はありますか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HttpServletRequest.getAttributeNames()`で全属性名のリストを取得して、そのリストの各要素(属性名)をキーに`HttpServletRequest.getAttribute()`を呼び出すことで属性値を確認できます。

ただ、属性値は任意のJavaオブジェクトなので、JSON形式では確認できません。Jacksonなどのライブラリ使ってやりたいことは実現できるかもしれませんが。

Comment: getAttributeNames()で要素毎にJSONするようにします。ありがとうございました